# ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown shows leak on Win8.1 but not Win7

Tags: delphi

ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown = true in my Delphi XE app. On my Win7 computer I see no memory leak info on close but on a Win8 computer a small memory leak message is reported. In both cases I merely open the app and then close it. Is there really a memory leak I have missed or is this a problem with Win 8.1?

Comment: Chances are that the RTL/VCL/FMX is creating a global object at startup and is not being freed at exit.  It is not unheard of for the RTL/VCL/FMX to do that. But, if that were the case, Embarcadero should be registering it as a known leak to the memory manager so it is not reported as a leak. So either you have encountered an object that is expected to leak but is not being registered, or it is a real unexpected leak. Either way, do what David said and use the full version of FastMM to track it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory manager leak reporting mechanism is reliable. It would appear that you have a leak that only manifests on certain systems. The issue is very likely not in the operating system, but rather in your code. Or perhaps in the Embarcadero library code.

But trust the memory manager. In my experience, when it tells you that there is a leak, there is a leak. One caveat there is that the IDE debugger will sometimes allocate memory in your process, which it then leaks. So when debugging you will sometimes see memory leaks that are false positives because they are caused by the debugger. But that's not the scenario here. Your process really is leaking.

Get yourself to the machine where the memory leak is reported, and debug the leak there. You'll likely do this more effectively with the full version of FastMM which gives much more detailed information for leaked memory blocks.